# R/ggplot error: too large for hashing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a time series graph using ggplot, however whenever the size of the data frame is greater than around 600, ggplot throws the following error:

> Error in anyDuplicated.default(breaks) :  length 1136073601 is too
>   large for hashing

In fact, it just gave me the same error when I try to plot 400 items.

The data is melted like so, except there are four variables- speed, dir, temp and pressure:

```
                   time variable       value
1   2006-07-01 00:00:00    speed    4.180111
2   2006-07-02 00:00:00    speed    5.527226
3   2006-07-09 00:00:00    speed    6.650821
4   2006-07-16 00:00:00    speed    4.380063
5   2006-07-23 00:00:00    speed    5.641709
6   2006-07-30 00:00:00    speed    7.636913
7   2006-08-06 00:00:00    speed    7.128334
8   2006-08-13 00:00:00    speed    4.719046
...
201 2006-07-01 00:00:00     temp   17.140069
202 2006-07-02 00:00:00     temp   17.517480
203 2006-07-09 00:00:00     temp   14.211002
204 2006-07-16 00:00:00     temp   20.121617
205 2006-07-23 00:00:00     temp   17.933492
206 2006-07-30 00:00:00     temp   15.244583
```

My code to plot these is based on what I found here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_date.html

```
qplot(time,value,data=test3,geom="line",group=variable) + 
+ facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

Any pointers and I'd be very grateful!!

To massage the date from character to date i'm using:

```
test$time <- strptime(test$time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
test$time <- as.POSIXct(test$time, format="%H:%M:%S")
test3 = melt(test,id="time")
```

class(test$time) returns `"[1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXct""`

Comment: Hmmmm.  Try updating plyr?  This may be related to an old bug.

Comment: I seem to have version 1.4. I tried to update but it seemed to update everything except Plyr! If I run this on my local machine using a text file it seems ok, but remotely using RMySQL it doesn't work

Comment: Also, incidentaly, what do I need to do to display gaps in the data where there is data missing?

Comment: Hmmm, have you turned the date column into real dates?  Or is it just characters?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed that section of code out. I've updated the code to show what I'm doing to get from character to date. I'm pretty sure this works since it works on my local machine.

Comment: Just to confirm; I ran this from the file and it still didn't work. How can I check which version plyr is- just using sessionInfo()?

Comment: Yes, `sessionInfo()` is fine, but best would be to send a reproducible example to the ggplot2 mailing list

Comment: Thanks Hadley- I'll sign up to the mailing list and get annoying people!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a timezone explicitly in the call to as.POSIXct(), as in https://gist.github.com/925852